# Reweighted mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose first I am interested in calculating the true mean of some random variable, X. Then it is well known that spread of the sample mean given by:

$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}$ (1)

decays like:

$\sigma_{\bar{X}} = \frac{\sigma_{X}}{\sqrt{N}}$ (2)

Now suppose instead that I wish to calculate the following quantity:

$y = \ln \langle e^{X} \rangle$,

where $\langle \rangle$ denotes the expectation value.

Can I somehow derive a relation similar to (2), which tells me how the sample mean given by:

$
\bar{y} = \ln (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}e^{X_{i}})
$

will converge?

PS: I'm sorry if my notation/language is not completely rigorous. I am very new to probability theory.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double rather than single dollar signs.